# Expected wait time on INSERT cards?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I am able to get cards to show up in my timeline, but they are taking a really long time (5-30 minutes). I can see the cards in the API's LIST command, but they don't show up on my glass. I am connected through my GS4, but I have the same problem over my home wifi and corporate wifi. Is this lag time to be expected?

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103365/mirror-api-latency-when-sending-something-to-a-timeline), there are several known issues that can cause this symptom where there is a delay between when your app pushes the item to the timeline and when the item actually shows up on the Glass. Some have been fixed, but not all, as delays still happen frequently for me.

Answer (score 0):

A slight delay is to be expected, but 5-10 minutes is really high. If you are seeing the same behavior with first party Glassware (GMail, Google+, etc.) it is best to follow up with your guide (support tab on MyGlass) to help investigate if the issue is coming from your device.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that if Glassware is hosted on Google infrastructure like App Engine, the response time is pretty fast.
If you really want steps to put your Maven project onto App Engine, I can provide that.